# How to provide new buttons based on user selection?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to provide the user with a button as follows:

```
<select id="test" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
    <option>Admin</option>
    <option>Employee</option>
</select>
```

and based on the option selected, another button will appear with other choices.

Here is my code:

```
Template.addingUser.helpers({
    userType: function () {
        if(t.find('#test').value == "Admin"){

        }else{

        }
    },

});
```

If am not mistaken, I can use something like:

```
$('#action-button').html('<a class="btn btn-primary edit_button"  href="' + Template.addingUser.__helpers.get('item')().sourceCode + '" onclick="">Download</a>');
```

In the case of an `action-button`, what about `select` option?

Or should I follow different approach to serve my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code could work, but it is not how we should do in Meteor. Instead you should make the selected option value a reactive data source, when it changes you could simple you button by helper:

```
const selectedValue = new ReactiveVar('default_value');

Template.addingUser.helpers({
  userType() {
    if (selectedValue.get() === 'Admin') {
      // return somehitng
    } else {

    }
  },
});

Template.addingUser.events({
  'change #test': function(e) {
    selectedValue.set(e.target.value);
  },
});
```

In this example, I use [ReactiveVar](https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html) to make selected option value reactive.

**Updated**

.js

```
const selectedValue = new ReactiveVar('default_value');

Template.addingUser.helpers({
  isAdmin() {
    return selectedValue.get() === 'Admin';
  },
  isNormalUser() {
    return selectedValue.get() === 'User';
  },
});

Template.addingUser.events({
  'change #test': function(e) {
    selectedValue.set(e.target.value);
  },
});
```

.html

```
<template name="addingUser">
  <!-- ... -->

  {{#if isAdmin}}
    <button>Button for admin</button>
  {{/if}}

  {{#if isNormalUser}}
    <button>Button for normal user</button>
  {{/if}}

  <!-- .. .-->
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, just one part I am confused in, about the return value, how do I return another "select" tag button?

Comment: Thanks a lot, works well. One last question, is it possible to access the "selectedValue" from other file? because I want to store the events in different file from he helpers, and I used to use sessions to serve this purpose. Am not sure about the case in reactive-var. I tried to implement sessions but it didn't work it out for me.

Comment: Ya, if you want to share variable across the application,  `Session` is a good way to go. I will add code use Session in the answer.

Comment: its okay, I managed to implement sessions, Thanks for the help :)